# What to use as an horizontal list separator?

Tags: html

`<tr/>`, `<separator/>`, or something else? What is the standard?

Answer (score 4):

`<hr>` == "horizontal rule"

`<tr>` is a table row, and there is no such thing as `<separator>`.

Oh, and [this is the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/).

Answer (score 0):

I usually just throw a `border` on the top or bottom of an element with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`<separator/>` is found at http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-xhtml2-20050527/mod-structural.html#edef_structural_separator

Comment: That's a working draft of XHTML 2.0, not part of an existing HTML standard.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I prefer to use

```
<ul><li>
```

and set the li display to inline, and float to left.
Give it a try!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such standard for it.
It will depend on how you want the browser to display your code.
you can use

---

to separate it with lines or 
 with new lines.
I'm not often used  or  to use as horizontal separator
you can also use css to add a border on your tags and add formating style.
if you say list to display horizontally
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/horizontal_master.htm